# React Apollo Query based on a condition

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-apollo

I'm currently building an app (hybrid mobile app) to show a list of records (places). Following is my requirement,

1) If the app is `online`, get the details from the server.

2) If the app is `offline`, get the details from the local storage.

I can get each condition working by its own. However (I'm fairly new to react and apollo-react), I'm not sure how to add a condition to the query.

below is an example of my query on getting the data from the server (I have this part working)

```
const client = new ApolloCient({
  uri: "/graphql"
});

const PLACES_LIST = gql`
  {
    places {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`;

class PlacesList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Query query={PLACES_LIST}>
          {({ loading, data }) => {
            if (loading) return "Loading....";
            const { places } = data;
            return places.map(place => (
              <PlaceDetail
                key={place.id}
                place={place}
              ></PlaceDetail>
            ));
          }}
        </Query>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

pseudocode for this I'm thinking would be,

```
if (online) {
  # run apollo client
} else {
  # read from the local storage
}
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction. TIA.

Also, I'm using a latest version of react and I have the flexibility of using react hooks if that required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const client = new ApolloCient({
  uri: "/graphql"
});

const PLACES_LIST = gql`
  {
    places {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`;

class PlacesList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Query query={PLACES_LIST}>
          {({ loading, data, error }) => {
            // There is also an error parameter from the hook
            if (loading) return "Loading....";
            // Here You can decide if its a connection error or smt other. 
            // I would recoment the fetchPolicy="network-only" prop for your <Query> in this case
            if(error) {
              return localstorage.getItem("Smt");
            } else {
              const { places } = data;
              return places.map(place => (
                <PlaceDetail
                  key={place.id}
                  place={place}
                ></PlaceDetail>
              ));
            }
          }}
        </Query>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, @peter this is what I needed :). I should be able to extend this solution for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to check for network connection using [the navigator interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator). I am not sure if navigator.onLine is available in hybrid mobile apps, but it would be easy to check.
You could do something like:

```js
render(){
 const isOnline = navigator.onLine
 return (
    <div>
      {isOnline ? (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}></ApolloProvider>
      ) : (
        <LocalStorageComponent />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer @Moi, this solution looks cleaner to me.  